# kafka stream: different objects in same topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two projets, the first is the producer and the second is the consumer. In the producer i send many objects of different types in the same topic, and in the comsumer i make the payload of the type Object then i used instanceof to tell the difference between objects the comes from the producer. But this method is not working. How can i get the different objects from the same topic ?

```
@StreamListener(ConventionStreams.INPUT)
public void on(@Payload Object object, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
    if (object instanceof IbanAgreementAssignedEvent) {
    IbanAgreementAssignedEvent event = (IbanAgreementAssignedEvent) object;
    logger.info("Received BankDataCreatedEvent: {}. Partition: {}. Offset: {}", event ,
            headers.get(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID), headers.get(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "not working"? some details would help with being able to tell what is wrong

Comment: @wcarlson when i debug the method, i find that the object returns a string `object= "{"externalId":"xxxxx", "name":"ppppp"}"`, so it does not enter into the if.